# How to change height using DOM .style property by passing an array value in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have to change the height of bars and make it equal to the random value that my loop generates. This value has to edit the bar-style class of my CSS under the `div` tag. I can change width, color, etc., when I use style property, however I cannot pass my random int value as height for some reason. I tried using template literals but that does not seem to work.

```js
let bars = [];
let arr_length = 10;
const sortArea = document.querySelector(".sort-area");

for (let i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) {
  // height of bars
  bars.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101));
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  sortArea.append(div);
  div.classList.add("bar-style");
  const barStyle = document.querySelectorAll(".bar-style");

  barStyle[i].style.height = `${bars[i]}`; //<-- main issue
}
```

```css
.bar-style {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1.25px;
  background-color: #f1ff5c;
  width: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Sorting Visualiser</h1>
      <nav>
        <button class="btn new-array">New Array</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn bubble">Bubble Sort</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn selection">Selection Sort</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn insertion">Insertion Sort</button>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="sort-area"></div>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js_files/arr.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

strong text

Comment: height requires units of measure also

Answer (score 3):

You are not adding the unit of measurement.

You could do like this:

```
barStyle[i].style.height = `${bars[i]}px`;
```

Comment: I feel very dumb that I missed the px, It worked!